Mocking hook return values in storybook
I'm using vite and typescript in React project.
I have several hooks in a hooks dir, for example:

'./hooks/queries/getWallets.tsx'
'./hooks/mutations/addWallet.tsx'

According to the docs, I should create a sameFileName.mock.tsx
So it would look like ./hooks/queries/getWallets.mock.tsx and so on.
The storybook docs, here, https://storybook.js.org/docs/writing-stories/mocking-data-and-modules/mocking-modules
Say that I would need to add an additional import field in my package.json and use subpath modules.
"imports": {
    "#useGetWallets": {
      "storybook": "./src/hooks/queries/useGetWallets.mock.tsx",
      "default": "./src/hooks/queries/useGetWallets.tsx"
    }
  }

Does this mean, I would need to create a separate mock field, for every hook that I use?
Ideally I can use relative imports in my .stories.tsx file, but that doesn't seem to work. I find really strange that I would need to create a path for every custom hook.
